# SAS macro inside data step runs parallelized? Is It possible?

Tags: parallel-processing, sas, sas-macro

I have the following table **process_table**

| table | index |
| --- | --- |
| TABLE_001 | 1 |
| TABLE_002 | 2 |
| TABLE_003 | 3 |
| TABLE_004 | 4 |

And a macro for create tables that i called type_a tables, using lines from process_table.

So, for example, when input was **TABLE_001** will generate **TABLE_001_A**.

```
%macro create_table_type_a(table_name);

proc sql;
  create table temp.&table_name._A as
  select 
    /*some process*/
  from &table_name
quit;

%mend create_table_type_a;
```

And then I run

```
data _null_;
  set process_table;
  call execute('%create_table_type_a('||table||')');
run;
```

Well, I have two doubts.

1 - Does SAS process the macro sequential, one line after other, or is parallelized? I didn't find the answer on internet.

2 - If It was not parallelized, is it possible do it using the same startegy? The tables to be processed are huge, and i dont know how to parallize the process on SAS.

Thanks.

Comment: How huge? Do you have a license for SAS/CONNECT? What is your SAS Set up?

Comment: https://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2018/15_Final_Paper_PDF.pdf

Comment: @Reeza , the number of observations in each table are between 500Millions and 800M. Yes, we have license and a tough server. It's Finance Industry. Doesn't know the set up, is is config in another team. Thanks.

Comment: In terms of set up, is it SAS Viya, SAS Server, EG/Studio? Do you use RSUBMIT at all?

Comment: `Proc DS2` can define and execute threads.  How applicable to your *some process* would need additional information

Comment: @Reeza We use EG/Studio. I didn't know rsubmit. It seems to do the job! thanks. \o/

Answer (score 1):

Good question.

1. No. The macros are run 'sequential', meaning that it runs %create_table_type_a(TABLE_001) before %create_table_type_a(TABLE_002) and so on. This is because Call Executes merely 'stacks' the macro calls in the data step and executes them after the data step has executed.
2. It is possible, but probably advanced. Reezas question of 'how huge' is pretty relevant before moving into advanced solutions of running macros in parallel.

Comment: Oh no, I suspected :/ . Observations between 500M and 800M. :(. Thanks

Comment: Anytime. Since you have SAS/Connect, that is probably the way to go in terms of performance. See the blog post below for a nice example

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2021/01/13/running-sas-programs-in-parallel-using-sas-connect/

Answer (score 1):

You could spawn separate SAS processes for each macro call (within its own program), then wait for both to finish before proceeding.

Example

```
%MACRO SPAWN(PGM,JOBID) ;
  systask command "/path/to/sasexe /path/to/programs/&PGM" status=job_&JOBID taskname="job_&JOBID" ;
%MEND ;
 
/* Run jobs asynchronously */
%SPAWN(Program1.sas,pgm1) ;
%SPAWN(Program2.sas,pgm2) ;

/* Wait for both to finish */   
waitfor _ALL_ job_pgm1 job_pgm2 ;

/* ... continue processing ... */
```